# what is opentelemetry instrumentations package to capture Node JS application server-side fetch/xhr calls

Tags: node.js, open-telemetry, telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm looking to set up OpenTelemetry for my Node.js application. The application consists of Node.js service running an HTTP server that's accessed by various web services. Within this Node.js server, I also initiate some REST API calls to other services. My objective is to capture the response times of these APIs along with their respective paths. However, the current functionality of the httpInstrumentation package within OpenTelemetry only allows me to retrieve the current service path and time, but it doesn't cover the APIs called from within the services